# Debian: Blank screen following login after systemd upgrade

Tags: debian, systemd, networkmanager, i3-window-manager

I am running Debian sid with the slim login manager and i3. I recently upgraded systemd. The update removed consolekit and switched to logind. Since that upgrade, the system hangs after login with a blank screen. If I wait a couple of seconds, then switch to tty1 and then back to tty2, the freeze is resolved and i3 starts normally.

The slim log file contains entries:
`slim: waiting for X server to begin accepting connections.`

The problem does not appear to be with slim or i3 as the system also hangs on login when I switch to lightdm or mate.

The problem seems to be related to network manager. When I disable network manager, the system is not freezing at all. However, even with network manager enabled `systemd-analyze blame` entries all have less than 1 second, so apparently nothing is waiting.

I tried masking NetworkManager-wait-online as well as ModemManager.service and systemd-networkd-wait-online.service but it did not help.

In `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` there is simply a delay:

```
...
[     5.845] (II) event6  - ThinkPad Extra Buttons: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Switch
[     5.845] (II) event6  - ThinkPad Extra Buttons: device is a keyboard
[     5.845] (II) event6  - ThinkPad Extra Buttons: device is a switch device
[     5.846] (II) event6  - ThinkPad Extra Buttons: device removed
[     5.868] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/thinkpad_acpi/input/input8/event6"
[     5.868] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ThinkPad Extra Buttons" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[     5.868] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     5.868] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "de"
[     5.871] (II) event6  - ThinkPad Extra Buttons: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard Switch
[     5.871] (II) event6  - ThinkPad Extra Buttons: device is a keyboard
[     5.871] (II) event6  - ThinkPad Extra Buttons: device is a switch device
[    21.712] (II) event4  - Power Button: device removed
[    21.732] (II) event8  - Video Bus: device removed
[    21.768] (II) event3  - Sleep Button: device removed
[    21.784] (II) event16 - Integrated Camera: Integrated C: device removed
[    21.816] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[    21.868] (II) event7  - TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint: device removed
[    21.900] (II) event6  - ThinkPad Extra Buttons: device removed
[    21.916] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[    22.548] (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
[    22.583] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "LGD", prod id 728
[    22.583] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Somewhat misleadingly, `systemd-analyze blame` is not the right tool to find out about services that stall the system. `systemd-analyze critical-chain` revealed that `virtualbox-service` was the culprit. Disabling this service solved the problem.